# Subgroup circle question

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $r$ be a positive real number. Let $S_r = \{α ∈ C∗ : |α| = r \}$. For what values of $r$ will $S_r$ be a
>   subgroup of $C^∗$ ?

Is the answer $r=0$ only? Since additive or multiplicative closure wont exist for values bigger than $0$. Also what would the identity element here is?

Comment: What about $r=1$?  Note:  nobody asked about additive properties.  This is a question about subgroups of the multiplicative group (to which $\alpha=0$ does not belong.)

Comment: it wont exist? For example 1+0i and 0+1i are in the group but 1+1i isnt in the group

Comment: If $r = 0$ then $Sr = \emptyset$. Is that a group? Also, you don't have to worry about addition, the only operation on $C^*$ (as a group) is multiplication.

Comment: Once again, nobody asked about additive properties.  The question only concerns multiplication.

Comment: Also $r$ is a **positive** real number, so you don't need to consider $r = 0$.

Comment: Hint. What is the length of the product of two complex numbers?

Comment: So its a sub group for any positive r?

Comment: Slow down.  Think about what the question is asking.  Among other things, you need to show that  $|\,\alpha_1\,|=|\,\alpha_2\,|=r\implies |\, \alpha_1\times \alpha_2\,|=r$.  Is that true for, say, $r=2$?

Comment: I guess not. It looks like its only true for r=1?

Comment: So, go through the list of things you have to prove to show that $r=1$ works and prove them all.

Answer (score 0):

If $S_r$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$, then $1 \in S_r$ and so $r=1$.

Conversely, $S_1$ is a clearly a subgroup of $\mathbb C^*$.